# how to conditionally render a mobile nav in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, conditional-rendering

I am new to gatsby and server side rendering, although I've worked with react quite a bit before. I wrote a bit of code that checks for the window size and then renders either the nav or the mobile nav based on the width. However, when I tried to test-deploy, I discovered that the window object is not available when you use server side rendering. My question is, is there any way i can modify my code to still work? or should I just rebuild everything with sass and media queries?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
// import "./header.module.scss"
import HeaderStyles from "./header.module.scss"
import Logo from "../images/newlogo@2x.png"
import Nav from "./nav"
const Header = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const [isDesktop, setDesktop] = useState(window.innerWidth > 768)

  const updateMedia = () => {
    setDesktop(window.innerWidth > 768)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateMedia)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateMedia)
  })
  const [menuActive, setMenuState] = useState(false)
  return (
    <header
      className={menuActive ? HeaderStyles.mobileNav : HeaderStyles.header}
    >
      <Link to="/" className={HeaderStyles.title}>
        {/* {data.site.siteMetadata.title} */}
        <img src={Logo} height="60" />
      </Link>
      {isDesktop ? (
        <Nav />
      ) : (
        //hamburger
        <div
          onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuActive)}
          className={`${HeaderStyles.navIcon3} ${
            menuActive ? HeaderStyles.open : ""
          }`}
        >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      )}
      {menuActive ? <Nav /> : null}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the [`window` object (or other global objects such as `document`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) directly in your code. This is because `gatsby develop` is rendered by the browser, where there's a `window` object, however `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server (your machine or you build system) where's there's no `window`.

If you don't want to redo your code with SCSS and mediaqueries (preferred version and more native), you need to make a condition above every use of `window` object. In your case, you need to make it when the DOM tree is loaded (`useEffect` with empty `deps`, `[]`). Something like this should work:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
// import "./header.module.scss"
import HeaderStyles from "./header.module.scss"
import Logo from "../images/newlogo@2x.png"
import Nav from "./nav"
const Header = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const [isDesktop, setDesktop] = useState(false)

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
      setDesktop(window.innerWidth > 768)
    }
  },[])

  const updateMedia = () => {
    setDesktop(window.innerWidth > 768)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateMedia)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateMedia)
  })
  const [menuActive, setMenuState] = useState(false)
  return (
    <header
      className={menuActive ? HeaderStyles.mobileNav : HeaderStyles.header}
    >
      <Link to="/" className={HeaderStyles.title}>
        {/* {data.site.siteMetadata.title} */}
        <img src={Logo} height="60" />
      </Link>
      {isDesktop ? (
        <Nav />
      ) : (
        //hamburger
        <div
          onClick={() => setMenuState(!menuActive)}
          className={`${HeaderStyles.navIcon3} ${
            menuActive ? HeaderStyles.open : ""
          }`}
        >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      )}
      {menuActive ? <Nav /> : null}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Keep in mind that this approach will create a small blink (a few `ms`) until the code knows what's the `window`'s with and, depending on your use-case, it may not work when resizing it, we should readapt a little bit the code to make it functional there.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can use the **gatsby-plugin-breakpoints** https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-breakpoints/?=break

```js
import { useBreakpoint } from 'gatsby-plugin-breakpoints';

import MobileOnlyComponent from './your/component/path';
// ...

const MyComponent = () => {
    const breakpoints = useBreakpoint();

    return (
        <AnyComponent>
            {/* Anything */}

            {/* <MobileOnlyComponent /> will only be displayed if max-width <= 320px  */}
            {breakpoints.xs ? <MobileOnlyComponent /> : null}
        </AnyComponent>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```